# 10 years ban. What next?

Tags: united-kingdom

In 2011 I solicited an agent to get me a school in London after which he procured the documents for filling out the application. Little did I know that the bank statement was fake, which resulted to a ban. Now nothing seems to have changed after 10 years. I applied for masters degrees recently and was asked to fill in an UKVI form before a CAS would be issued. But, to my dismay, the school said they can’t continue because of my previous immigration history. So what are my chances if I get a solicitor? Secondly the agent was based in the UK. So I reported the matter at the time to the police .

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89170/how-do-i-find-an-immigration-lawyer-solicitor-to-help-with-my-uk-visa-applicatio

Answer (score 8):

The end of your ban means that it is no longer completely impossible for you to get a visa, not that your deception attempt no longer counts against you. British Universities can get into trouble with the UK government if too many of their students on visa end up being illegal immigrants, and as such may be even more cautious.

Getting a UK solicitor might help if you have a complex case that needs to be properly presented, but they would need something to work with. My recommendation would be to pick a different country for your Master studies.

In these matters, you are responsible for the actions of your agent.